# Two way data binding in autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am having `Filter autocomplete` i,e **(Vehicle Type)** and `Select with multiple selection` i,e **(Vehicle model)**  components on the same page as shown in below image:

[image]

Here i want to performing **2-way data binding** with `Select with multiple selection`  component.

If i select `Vehicle Type` as **Cars** , then the cars  `Vehicle Model` as to come like this:

[image]

If i select  `Vehicle Type` as **Bikes** , then the bikes  `Vehicle Model` as to come like this:

[image]

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kxeab-5cvtnn?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts) link.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It just appears that youre telling us you can change `Cars` to `Bikes` and the checkboxes change accordingly

Comment: Ya i want to change the list(i,e check box) according to the change in `bike/cars`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kxeab-glx4vg

Comment: Thank for your answer.@chellappan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormControl have a valueChages method that returns an observable that emits the latest value.

Try this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.list = this.CarList;
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe((d) => {

      if (d === 'Cars') {
        this.list = this.CarList;
      } else {
        this.list = this.BikeList;
      }
    })
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kxeab-glx4vg